# Angular - icons missing after deploy

Tags: angular

I have an issue after deploying angular 5 project. I styled Add new button in style less, and I use it throughout the project, on multiple components, but after deployment the + icon is not appearing everywhere. So, Add New button shows fine in one component and the + icon is missing in another component. Same goes for many other icons.

All of those icons are .png, while .svg's are showing.

Also, I get this warning in console about fonts:

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: ... .woff
OTS parsing error: incorrect file size in WOFF header
Failed to decode downloaded font: ... .ttf
OTS parsing error: DSIG: misaligned table
```

Anyone had similar issue?